# Apache dispatcher get header content in logs

Tags: apache, logging, dispatcher

I get log below from dispatcher. I need to be able to dump request header content and and also content of body if possible. Can someone please suggest how to do same.

```
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] checking [url here]
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] request URL has no extension: url
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] cache-action for [url]: NONE
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Creating new socket: <ip:port>
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Connected to backend 0 (backend ip)
    Adding request header: referer
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Adding request header: user-agent
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Adding request header: content-type
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Adding request header: content-length
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Adding request header: accept-encoding
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Adding request header: accept-language
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Adding request header: accept
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Adding request header: host
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Adding request header: cookie
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Adding request header: Via
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Adding request header: X-Forwarded-For
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Adding request header: X-Forwarded-SSL
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Adding request header: X-Forwarded-SSL-Cipher
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Adding request header: X-Forwarded-SSL-Session-ID
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Adding request header: Server-Agent
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Sending request body to remote server
    [dateTime] [E] [pid processID (tid threadID)] Error while reading request body.
    [dateTime] [D] [pid processID (tid threadID)] No socket reuse: response body not fully consumed
    [dateTime] [I] [pid processID (tid threadID)] "POST url" 400 - 3810ms []
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:
set DispatcherLogLevel to Trace and values shall show